# Does GWT's ActivityMapper violate the Liskov Substitution Principle?

Tags: gwt, liskov-substitution-principle

In my GWT application, I have a class like so:

```
public class AppActivityMapper implements ActivityMapper {

    @Override public Activity getActivity(Place place) {

        if(place instanceof ThisPlace) {
            return new ThisActivity((ThisPlace)place);
        }
        if(place instanceof ThatPlace) {
            return new ThatActivity((ThatPlace)place);
        }
        if(place instanceof AnotherPlace) {
            return new AnotherActivity((AnotherPlace)place);
        }
        // you get the idea
    }
}
```

The ActivityMapper, Activity, and Place objects are part of the framework, and the interface implies that this is how it was meant to be used.

However, according to the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/lsp.pdf), a method that accepts a type but does a type check for subclasses to infer what action to take is a violation of the principle.

Is GWT's ActivityMapper interface by nature encouraging a violation of the LSP? Or is there another LSP-compliant way to code that method that I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The role of the `ActivityMapper` is to map a `Place` to an `Activity`, where the rules for the mapping are left entirely free.
What makes for that kind of if/else cascade is that Java doesn't support [multiple dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch), but in my opinion it doesn't mean it's violating the LSP (or at least, well, you have no other choice in Java, so it's a non-issue; you could use a visitor pattern –that's what Spring Roo generates– but that doesn't change much things).

Comment: Upon more reading, I guess violating the LSP depends on whether or not you can break a client by having it call this method with a subclass. And this seems to actually be the intent of the mapping method, so in this case maybe an if/else cascade of instanceof's isn't automatically a violation of LSP. Thanks for mentioning the Visitor Pattern... there seems to be more discussion of implementations of this method [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802747/eliminating-gwt-activitymapper-boilerplate).